# Adding new auto-updating fields like [Shape_Area] using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, update, shape-area, calculate-geometry

Currently in ArcGIS Pro, any polygon feature class in a gdb will have the fields [Shape_Area] and [Shape_Length] and these will be updated to reflect any changes to the feature geometry. This is very useful, but even better would be the ability to add other fields that perform similarly. For example, a field called [Shape_Acres] that would update automatically and have (not surprisingly) the acreage of the features in it; or [Point_X] and [Point_Y] coordinate fields in a point feature class.

Is this possible?

I made a simple tool that puts [Shape_Acres] into any projected polygon feature class and calculates it correctly based on the projected coordinate system, and that's pretty good, but I still have to remember to do it.

Comment: Those "fields" aren't really fields, but *properties*, which are exposed as fields. You can't add a property. You can certainly remember to run your script.

Comment: [Attribute rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/geodatabases/overview/calculation-attribute-rules.htm)